# Converting an array to cursor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Cursors can be easily converted to arrays using `.toArray(foo)` method:

```
var cursor = col.find({});
cursor.toArray(function (err, itemsArray) {
   /* do something */
});
```

But is it possible to convert `itemsArray` in a cursor so I will have all cursor functions?

```
var newCursor = foo (itemsArray);
typeof newCursor.toArray === "function" // true
```

Comment: Am I right that you want to emulate MongoDB cursor api?

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny If possible I don't only want to emulate but to really use an existing api for converting an array to cursor.

Comment: I doubt that such an API exists.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny Why not just create your own iterator? It's pretty simple. See the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it is all just JavaScript so why not create your own iterator:

```js
var Iterator = function () {
    var items = [];
    var index = 0;

    return {

        "createCursor" : function (listing) {
            items = listing;
        },

        "next" : function () {
            if ( this.hasNext() ) {
                return items[index++];
            } else {
                return null;
            }
         },

         "hasNext" : function () {
             if ( index < items.length ) {
                 return true;
             } else {
                 return false;
             }
         }
     }
}();
```

So then you use it like this with an array:

```js
var cursor = new Iterator();
cursor.createCursor( array );

cursor.next();    // returns just the first element of the array
```

So just a general way to write an iterator. If you want more functionality then just add the other methods to the prototype.

Comment: @IonicăBizău You basically just changed a "cursor" into an "array". So there is no "API" available. Writing an iterator is quite trivial in any language, as has been shown.

Comment: You're correct. I waited the official answer from Mongo devs, and this is: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-164

Comment: Can you please make it possible to pipe such an array to response? `cursor.pipe(res)`

Comment: @IonicãBizãu The node driver supports conversion to the [stream interface](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#stream) out of the box. If you wanted to implement your own streaming iterator you can follow the [streaming interface guide](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#stream)

Comment: How to reopen  request of https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-164 ? It is not a driver responsability, it is a orthogonal semantic complement of a language constructor... Mongo framework, nowadays, is like a language...